# Is there a Windows Group or Privilege that would allow a user to view, but not edit, users in Computer Management?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, group-policy

Preferably they would be able to open up their properties and so forth, but not actually edit them. I'd settle for user just being able to essentially view a list either.

Answer (score 0):

No special privilege needed. Theres a kind-of wizard for this.

- Install remote administration tools on the PC belonging to the user (theres a different one for each version of windows).
- Open Active directory users and computers on a DC.
- Navigate to your OU branch where your users accounts are
- Right click on the OU
- Choose 'delegate control'
- Follow the wizard

You can choose to let just one user or a group of users to be able to read or modify selected attributes, which you can choose.

The idea is that you can have a selected user who can, say, update phone numbers and job descriptions, or have a helpdesk who can change passwords for non-priv users.